# Flutter Debug/Gradle build Error ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: debugging, flutter, build.gradle

Right after I got a notification and upgraded flutter:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Cannot write to file 'C:\Users\Karim.KARIM\Coding\Flutter' specified for property 'outputFiles' as it is a directory.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

After I tried changing my targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 29, I'm kind of hopeless. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same issue and i got it resolved by cleaning the project.

1. from command prompt navigate to your project directory.
2. use the following command: flutter clean
3. then you can run the app using: flutter run

or run your project on VScode

1. View->Command pallet ( Or press ctrl+shift+p)
2. type "Flutter: Clean Project"
3. press F5 to run the app

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making your project by a commanf "flutter create project_name" then it might be possible it will not take sdk path so make your project with android studio and it will work becuase then it will have sdk path as well